# How is tensorflow tf.add implemented?

Tags: tensorflow

I was hoping someone more familiar with the TensorFlow library could help with a simple question. I would like to know how the tensorflow add operation is implemented.

Other tensorflow ops are registered and defined kernels, but where/how are basic arithmetic operations handled?

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/kernels

Comment: Every op is defined like the what the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) says, `tf.add` is not an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`tf.add()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add) Python function is an automatically generated wrapper function (currently in the module `tensorflow.python.ops.gen_math_ops`) that adds a node to the current default TensorFlow [graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graphs).

When you run a graph containing that node (via [`tf.Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run)), the TensorFlow runtime will invoke an instance of [`BinaryOp<Device, tensorflow::functor::add>`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/04c318b69c5b565436cfeeaab1cb7fd5419dde27/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_ops_common.h#L75), which is contains some code that is common across all componentwise binary operations (e.g. for broadcasting and argument validation), and an invocation of [`tensorflow::functor::add()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/04c318b69c5b565436cfeeaab1cb7fd5419dde27/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_ops.h#L666), which uses Eigen's `scalar_sum_op` to perform the addition.

Comment: Hey @mrry, really appreciate the guidance. This helps clear up what is happening under the hood.